# Why are there owners willing to pay so much for sports teams?

Tags: finances

I found [a list of most valuable sports teams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbes%27_list_of_the_most_valuable_sports_teams), and I was amazed at the valuations. Why are there owners willing to drive the value of these teams so high?

For example, **Real Madrid** is listed with a value of **USD 3.65 Billion**.

[image: Chart showing valuation of American Football's Dallas Cowboys as $4.0 Billion and Football's Real Madrid as $3.65 Billion]

We know that they are getting revenue through sponsorships, television broadcast rights fees, Internet broadcasting, and match ticket sales. Do those together justify such high valuations?

Comment: "Too much" seems to be entirely opinion based to me - that's the value because that's what someone else would have to pay to own the team.

Comment: @PhilipKendall i am curious to know why someone will pay that much to purchase the team!.....

Comment: OK, then ask that question. "Why are there owners willing to pay to purchase sports teams when the valuations are so high?" That's not opinion-based, although it does ask for some speculation about motivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Application of Income Approach for Valuation of Football Club by *Ilia Solntsev* mention teams are getting revenues through number of causes namely:

> Matchday, Broadcasting Revenues, Sponsorship, Merchandising, Stadium Revenues, Additional Sources of Income(pen branded restaurants, clubs, fitness centers etc.), Fans

but that **can not justify** those high valuations. Because clubs are valuated by different technique, above valuation is of *Forbes Valuation Technique* and different values will use different data to valuate clubs.

Look at this example used by *Markham*:

---

Anomalies in football club valuation – Tottenham Hotspur 2012:

Market Capitalisation Value :  £83.6m
Revenue Multiples Value : £245.2m
Forbes Value : £351.1m

---

Which clearly shows different method yields different club value.

From "What is the optimal method to value a football club?" by *Tom Markham*.

Traditional corporate valuation techniques are Market capitalisation, Discounted Cash flow (DCF) models, Bankruptcy valuation. And methodologies used within the football sector to ascertain a club’s worth are Revenue multiples approach, Forbes valuation, Broker valuation and Multivariate model for EPL club valuation.

**At last**, valuations are done with different set of data and owner may not pay the same amount as valuation.

Forbes valuation hasn't been accurate to predict the sales of team i.e; Real Madrid valuation of USD 3.65 Billion doesn't mean that cost of buying Real is 3.65 Billion.

> Results show that on average the transaction cost of the North American sports franchises was 27% higher than Forbes had estimated for 2004. Forbes estimates were between 59.2% lower (Manchester City in 2008) and 69.1% higher (Liverpool in 2010) than actual transaction prices.